# SoundCloud API /users/{id}/playlists not working with some users

Tags: soundcloud

I'm getting lists of playlists for specific users, however recently it does not work in 1 case that i know of, maybe something changed but here's the case:

Not working example:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/110564649/playlists?client_id=MYCLIENTID
```

Working example:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/968/playlists?client_id=MYCLIENTID
```

The not working example refers to [this](https://soundcloud.com/noisysongbird) user.

Anyone experiencing the same issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoundCloud has given this answer for tracks and it probably applies to playlists as well.

> Yep -- there's many reasons that a track might not show up to you. It could be taken down by the rightsholder of the track, made private or deleted by the uploader, or (and this is the tricky one) blocked in certain territories. Calculating the policies of all of the tracks of a user every time it is fetched isn't quite feasible, so sometimes this number will be inaccurate (depending on who is asking and where they are).

My guess is they've made their playlist page private, but there's no way to tell (yet) through the API.

Comment: If they made their playlist private, then i wouldn't be able to navigate to their playlist trough the browser, right? I can navigate to the one playlist that isn't working, so i guess it must be one of the other reasons you mentioned.

Comment: Well it's not documented by SoundCloud, so I don't know if the private flag only applies to the API and not when browsing SoundCloud. Sorry.